# H1 tag in header ok?

Tags: html

Is it ok to use a h1 tag in the header of a site? I don't mean to replace the logo but as a bit of text next to it with keywords.

The body h tags would all be h2.

Only reason im thinking this is because the site is more or less a personel project site and the design is more of a news or directory layout with not much need for a h1 tag in the body.

Or will this somehow get my penalized by google?

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla Foundation:

> ...you should consider avoiding using  more than once on a page; by convention, it's used for the page's displayed title, with all headings below starting with . When using sections, you should use one  per section...

That said here you have the link to it for further knowledge:

[Heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)